# Does sequence of Sqoop commands matter?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Does it matter in what sequence I put my Sqoop commands?

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/nba --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --username root --table player --as-textfile --fields-terminated-by '\t' --target-dir /user/Inayath/sqooptest  -m 1
```

For example, with the above code if I were to swap --as-textfile with --target-dir would it matter?

Comment: it does not matter.

Comment: Sequence of the options in the command don't matter.

You may check the import with [sqoop-eval](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_eval_literal).

Answer (score 1):

no it does not matter. sometimes it may give syntax error but if the code is syntactically correct there should not be any difference between the outputs.